# We decided to leave early

Tags: active-voice

We decided to leave early. 
How to change this into passive form?

Are they ?

We decided that we should leave early. 
Or
We decided early should be left. 
Please help me teachers.

Comment: One can try to form a passive voice sentence like this: "To leave early was decided by us". Awkward, though...

Comment: Sir,  what about this? It was decided that we should leave early.

Comment: Neither of them are passive, they are obviously active past tenses !

Comment: Please change it in passive

Comment: "It was decided" is passive voice.

Comment: Cardinal sir,  How would you like to change this into passive? Please share your fruitful views.

Comment: Is this part of your homework? Why are you trying to make this passive?

Comment: A fruitful view is to question the question: What grammar book is this exercise from? Why does the book include this question? What is the point of the exercise? -- If the book doesn't make it clear, there would be no point in pursing this, and this would become a pointless question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (simplified) sentence structures of active and passive voices are:

> - subject + **activeVoiceVerb** + *object*
>
>   (I drink water.)

and

> - *object* + **passiveVoiceVerb** + subject
>
>   (Water is drunk by me.)

---

If we apply the rule to the original sentence:

> We **decided** *to leave early*.

we have:

- subject: we
- **activeVoiceVerb: decided**
- *object: to leave early*

Therefore, the passive voice will look like:

> *To leave early* **was decided** by us.

However, this sounds quite unnatural to me, and therefore I do not recommend its use.

Answer (score -1):

My best guess is that "an early leave was made". But if you want to go with the same subject, it is pretty much impossible.